# Font asset loading/displaying bitmap issue

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, truetype

I am trying to load a font (arial) from a .ttf file and using the STB TrueType library: https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h and display it on the screen.

It is working when displaying the 1st letter in the characters array 'a', but every character after that it looks all distorted and weird, see example below

Comes out as 'a' (correct):

[image: Correct]

Should be 'b':

[image: Incorrect]

I think maybe I am misunderstanding/misapplying how the memory ends up being laid out, or how the file is being read?

Here is the relevant code:

(In win32 platform layer file)

```
struct character_bitmap
{
    unsigned char* memory;
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct font_buffer
{
    character_bitmap* memory;
    float size;
};

static font_buffer font_bitmaps;

void test_load_arial(float size)
{
    if (font_bitmaps.memory)
    {
        // VirtualFree(font_bitmaps.memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        free(font_bitmaps.memory);
    }

    unsigned char* ttf_buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1 << 25);
    stbtt_fontinfo font;

    fread(ttf_buffer, 1, 1 << 25, fopen("c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf", "rb"));
    stbtt_InitFont(&font, (unsigned char*)ttf_buffer, stbtt_GetFontOffsetForIndex((unsigned char*)ttf_buffer, 0));

    // int char_bitmap_width = (int)size;
    // int char_bitmap_height = (int)size;

    // unsigned int character_memory_size = ((int)size * (int)size) * 4 /*+ 8*/;
    // int font_memory_size = character_memory_size * 52;

    unsigned int font_memory_size = sizeof(character_bitmap) * 52;

    // font_bitmaps.memory = (character_bitmap*)VirtualAlloc(0, font_memory_size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    font_bitmaps.memory = (character_bitmap*)malloc(font_memory_size);

    char alphabet[53] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    character_bitmap* current_character = font_bitmaps.memory;
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        // current_character->width = char_bitmap_width;
        // current_character->height = char_bitmap_height;

        current_character->memory = stbtt_GetCodepointBitmap(&font, 0, stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight(&font, size), alphabet[i],
                                                 &current_character->width, &current_character->height, 0, 0);
        current_character++;
    }
}
```

(In different file, inside main update and render function which gets called every frame I call this function)

```
void test_render_text(offscreen_buffer* buffer, font_buffer* font_bitmaps)
{
    int width = font_bitmaps->memory[0].width;
    int height = font_bitmaps->memory[0].height;

    unsigned char* dest_row = (unsigned char*)buffer->memory
    unsigned char* source = font_bitmaps->memory[42].memory;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        unsigned int* dest_pixel = (unsigned int*)dest_row;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            unsigned char alpha = *source;
            *dest_pixel = ((alpha << 24)
                          | (alpha << 16)
                          | (alpha << 8)
                          | (alpha << 0));

            dest_pixel++;
            source++;
        }

        dest_row += buffer->pitch;
    }
}
```

Also posted on github if you want the full source to review/compile:
https://github.com/jackson-lenhart/loji

Comment: Even if a problem could be applied to multiple programming languages, please only tag the one you're actually programming in. For example, even if C and C++ might seem similar, there are quite a lot of differences that could make solutions in one language not valid in the other.

Comment: I can't compile your code. Where is `offscreen_buffer` defined? Are you creating a bitmap? Where? How do you print it?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Here is a link to it on github, would highly appreciate if you were to clone it and give it a try:
https://github.com/jackson-lenhart/loji

NOTE: You may want to turn volume off before running as there is a very loud buggy square wave attempt that plays right now

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Update: I fixed one of the problems, but it now renders only the lowercase 'a' successfully, the others are still all messed up. I pushed the updates to github, if you could take a look I would be ecstatic. I will edit the question later as well to reflect

Comment: Sure I'll have a look once you update the question. By the way, I assume you are aware that Windows has APIs for loading fonts and printing on bitmap. `AddFontMemResourceEx` will load the font temporarily. DirectWrite has additional functions...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thank you, I have updated the question. I was not aware of that specific Windows API, I am currently following a tutorial where the guy uses this library first, then shows the Windows stuff as well after that.

Comment: I can't seem to run that code without copying a whole bunch of files. Anyway, you can just create a memory bitmap, use `CreateFont(20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Arial");` select the font in to memory dc. Now you can use `TextOut(mem_hdc, 0, 0, "abc");` and then you save that in to bitmap file. It doesn't require additional libraries.